# How can I test a .class file was created?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng, dynamic-class-creation

I want to unit test my code which will have to create a .java file compile it and then the corresponding .class file should be created.

How can I create the test to see if the ".class" file is created? I have added test already for its existence, now I'm trying to test the file is a valid class file.

I tried

```
 try  {
      Class.forName("Hello");
      throw AssertError();
 } catch( ClassNotFoundException e ) {
 }

 program.createClass();
 Class.forName("Hello");
```

But I don't really know how to dynamically add the path where the file is created to the classpath.

**EDIT**

URL Class loaded does the work.

This is how my test looks like now.

```
@Test
void testHello() throws MalformedURLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    URL[] url = {
            new URL("file:/home/oreyes/testwork/")
    };

    try {
        new URLClassLoader(url).loadClass("Hello");
        throw new AssertionError("Should've thrown ClassNotFoundException");
    } catch ( ClassNotFoundException cnfe ){

    }
    c.process();
    new URLClassLoader(url).loadClass("Hello");
}
```

Comment: hehe  `testng`  is not a typo, but the name of the testing framework :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a new instance of an `URLClassLoader`, pointing to the root folder where you created the target class file. Then, use the `Class.forName(String,ClassLoader);` method with the dynamically created `URLClassLoader` to load the new class.

To show that it works, the following test case will create a source file, write some Java code in there and compile it using the Java 6 ToolProvider interfaces. Then, it will dynamically load the class using an URLClassLoader and invoke a reflective call to its class name to verify it's really this class which has been generated on the fly.

```
@Test
public void testUrlClassLoader() throws Exception {
    Random random = new Random();
    String newClassName = "Foo" + random.nextInt(1000);
    JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
    StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(null, null, null);
    List<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();
    File sourceFolder = new File(".");
    File sourceFile = new File(sourceFolder, newClassName + ".java");
    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(sourceFile);
    fileWriter.write("public class " + newClassName + " { { System.out.println(\""
            + newClassName + " loaded\"); }}");
    fileWriter.close();
    files.add(sourceFile);
    Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compilationUnits1 = fileManager
            .getJavaFileObjectsFromFiles(files);
    compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, null, null, null, compilationUnits1).call();
    fileManager.close();

    URL url = sourceFolder.toURI().toURL();
    URLClassLoader urlClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { url });
    Object newInstance = urlClassLoader.loadClass(newClassName).newInstance();
    assertEquals(newClassName, newInstance.getClass().getName());
}
```

Comment: I've tried ` new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{new URL("file:~/testwork")});` but is not working.

Comment: ~ is not a valid short cut for the home directory in Java.  It only works in some Unix programs.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of loading the class in order to verify it, you could shell out to a command like "file Hello.class" to see if it reports that it's a java class file, or even spawn a sub-process of java to load the class outside of your test JVM.

Comment: such as... `"javac Hello.java ; java Hello"`?  MMhhh could work. It is just that eventually this thing will create more and more stuff and I just wanted ( at this stage ) to test if the .class was created and if it was a valid java class ( my Hello.java is : `class Hello{}` )

Comment: Well, I didn't necessarily mean "javac Hello.java ; java Hello." You could just check with "file Hello.class" to see if the file is non-zero and has the right magic number to be a java class. Then if you want something stronger, you could have a new simple class that loads a your class by name with Class.forName("args[0]"). My point is that rather than restricting yourself to using the existing JVM, you can spawn a new process and work there.