# How to add deploy.jar to classpath?

Tags: java, classloader

I am facing the problem: I need to add `${java.home}/lib/deploy.jar` JAR file to classpath in the runtime (dynamically from java).

- The solution with `Thread#setContextClassLoader(ClassLoader)` (mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873916/is-it-possible-to-have-the-system-classloader-load-class-files-specified-at-run)) does not work because of [this bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6667564) (if somebody can explain what is really a problem – you are welcome).
- The solution with `-Xbootclasspath/a:"%JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib/deploy.jar"` does not work well for me, because I want to have "pure executable jar" as a deliverable: no wrapping scripts please (more over `%JAVA_HOME%` may not be defined in user's environment in Windows for example, plus I need to write a script per platform)
- The solution with merging `deploy.jar` file into my deliverable works only if I make a build on Windows platform. Unfortunately, when the deliverable is produced on build server running on Linux, I got Linux-dependant JAR, which does not execute on Windows – it fails with the trace below.

I have read [How the Java Launcher Finds Classes](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/findingclasses.html) and [Java programming dynamics: Java classes and class loading](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-dyn0429/) articles but I've got no extra ideas, how to correctly handle this situation.

Any advices or solutions are very welcomed.

Trace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.deploy.config.Config
    at com.sun.deploy.net.proxy.UserDefinedProxyConfig.getBrowserProxyInfo(UserDefinedProxyConfig.java:43)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.proxy.DynamicProxyManager.reset(DynamicProxyManager.java:235)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.proxy.DeployProxySelector.reset(DeployProxySelector.java:59)
...
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.deploy.net.proxy.DynamicProxyManager.getProxyList(DynamicProxyManager.java:63)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.proxy.DeployProxySelector.select(DeployProxySelector.java:166)
```

Answer (score 0):

Boot class path does not have a class loader, so it's impossible to add to it dynamically. However you can add a Class-Path: deploy.jar attribute to your MANIFEST.MF and require that your JAR be run with -Xbootclasspath/a:myjar.jar. If the deploy.jar will be in the same directory it will also be loaded in the boot class path.

Comment: @Jevgeni: Do I need to add `deploy.jar` to classpath, if you already add it to bootclasspath? I think - no. In any case, I wonder how to add this library dynamically. If you have solution on the top that I've mentioned, please, share.