# Suggestions for a java Mock File (to mock java.io.File)

Tags: java, unit-testing, file, mocking

Does anyone have suggestions for a java mock File object?
I Am using a thirdparty class which need to get a java.io.File object as argument.
I receive the data for this file in a stream over a webservice (also one of their products).

One solution is to write all this data to a file and offer this to the class. This is a solution I don't like: it takes away the advantage of using the webservice in stead of just downloading the file.

Quicker and more efficient would be to put this data from memory in a Mock File and offer this Mock File to the thirdparty class.

It would probably have to be a MockFile extending the java.io.File and overriding all the functions that do actual interfacing with the file on the hard disk.

I know the thirdparty should have used a stream as an input argument in stead of a file. However, this is beyond my influence.

Comment: Have you considered using [Commons VFS](http://commons.apache.org/vfs/)?

Comment: As marked above, this package seem to offer the solution I Am looking for... will let you know whether this is usefull.

Comment: Thanx for all answers...
It apears to me a Mock File is not the solution... the only thing I can do with this, is make an extended File object that generates automatically a file and give this to the thirdparty class.
For what i actually wanted.... the thirdparty class should have to accept an InputStream as argument.
But this can also be done by using the suggestion about the wrapper.
A bit frustrating the thirdparty class only accepts a file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just a suggestion based on my understanding of your question.
I believe, you must be doing something like this,

```
public void doSomething(){
      //Pre processing
       Object result=new ThirdPartyCode().actualMethod(file);
     //Post processing
}
```

Mock objects make more sense from an unit testing perspective.
Your objective is not to unit test the third party library function.Whereas it is to unit test doSomething() method. So probably you can create a wrapper around the third party function.Maybe something like this,

```
public class Wrapper implements MyWrapper{

   public Object invokeThirdPartyFunction(File file){
      new ThirdPartyCode().actualMethod(file);
   }
}
```

Now you can create a mock wrapper(implementing the same interface) and use this mock wrapper for all your junit cases.

Comment: Thanx, this in combination with the answer about common VFS will probably do the trick. (need something like the common VFS to create a virtual file while not actually creating the file on harddisk)

Answer (score 2):

Does the tested class only query the mock File's name, attributes etc., or does it actually attempt to open the file?

In the former case, you can easily create your mock using e.g. [EasyMock](http://easymock.org/) or an equivalent mocking framework.

The latter case is more tricky, and I am afraid if the input stream is created internally by the class, you have no choice other than actually creating a real test file on the HD.

Comment: It actually wants get (read) the data out of the file. So I Am looking for a mock file the overrides read as well...
And read from the data in the memory (in the mock file)
I know it's more tricky, but hopefully somebode already has done this...

Comment: @michel, the problem is, `File` is only "an abstract representation of file and directory pathnames" [(from the Javadoc)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html). So you can't read directly from it - you need to open a [`FileInputStream`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html) (or [`FileReader`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html)) for that.

Comment: I know, so need to return a file inputstream from this mock file object. Thanx for helping and thinking along, The suggestion below seems to offer the searched solution....

Comment: Part of what you suggested leeds to my end conclusion, what I want cannot be done. Need to actually make a file. The wrapper can only be used to auto generate a temp. file. For what I want, the thirdparty must add an option to pass an inputstream in stead of the File.

Comment: It may not be the best solution in this case, but you *can* mock an input stream (and just about anything else) with the JMockit mocking library. Even if said stream is created inside the third-party class.

Answer (score 1):

You could load the 3rd party code using an ASM based classloader that maps `java.io.File` to your own "fake" implementation. It's a bit of work, and needs to be performed carefully... For example you will need to also map `FileInputStream`, etc.

Comment: I wasn't looking for an answer anymore, but based on the nr of views this is a problem a lot of people are facing. This classloader however sounds like an interesting option for testing anyway! I saw something here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873916/is-it-possible-to-have-the-system-classloader-load-class-files-specified-at-run Maybe you can provide some urls for people who are going to give this option a try?

Answer (score 0):

You don't use file (or any external dependency in Unit tests). Except using mocks, your approaches will result in problematic tests.
See [this javaranch article](http://www.javaranch.com/unit-testing.jsp) for more

Comment: I Am aware of avoiding files in unit tests. That's why I was looking for a mockup or anything that can fake a file. Based on the nr. of views I see on this question, I Am not the only one facing this problem. I would rather here what I should do, than what I shouldn't do (especially if my question implies I know what I shouldn't do) :)