# Any way to mock File.exist()/ File.isFile() method with Mockito?

Tags: java, file, unit-testing, junit, mockito

```
ArrayList<File> m_files = new ArrayList<File>();
for(int i = 0; i < m_files.size(); i++) {
     File m_file = m_files.get(i);
     if(m_file.exists()) {
        FileUtils.deleteQuietly(m_file);
        if(m_file.isFile()) {
          m_log.error("Deleting file " + m_file.getName() +" fails");
          throw new ServiceUnavailableException("Not successfully delete the file " + m_file.getName());
        } else {
          m_log.info("Successfully delete the file " + m_file.getName());
        }
     }
  }
```

My code is about deleting some local files. I want to do a unit test for the situation when Deleting the file fails. Is there any way to mock file.exist()/file.isFile() or anyway to mock that static method FileUtiles.deleteQuitely() or other solutions?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11849728/simulate-file-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mock file class behavior as follows.

```
 File mockedFile = Mockito.mock(File.class);
 Mockito.when(mockedFile.exists()).thenReturn(true);
```

This [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Mockito/article.html) should help.

Edit...

You need to make the method testable. Method should take in the files it is operating on. The mocked objects should be passed as parameters. For example,

```
public void deleteMyFile(List<File> m_files){

  for(int i = 0; i < m_files.size(); i++) {
  File m_file = m_files.get(i);
  if(m_file.exists()) {
     FileUtils.deleteQuietly(m_file);
     if(m_file.isFile()) {
       m_log.error("Deleting file " + m_file.getName() +" fails");
       throw new ServiceUnavailableException("Not successfully delete the file " + m_file.getName());
     } else {
       m_log.info("Successfully delete the file " + m_file.getName());
     }
   }
  }
 }
```

And the test code would look like this.

```
@Test
public void test(){
    File mockedFile = Mockito.mock(File.class);
    Mockito.when(mockedFile.exists()).thenReturn(true);
    Mockito.when(mockedFile.isFile()).thenReturn(true);
    List<File> files = new ArrayList<>();
    files.add(mockedFile);
    MyTestClass myTestClass = new MyTestClass();
    myTestClass.deleteMyFile(files);
}
```

Comment: I tried this many times but still not work. I can mock other objects in this class but not work for File.

Answer (score 0):

U can mock static methods with power mock

```
    mockStatic(File.class);
    when(File.exists()).thenReturn(true);
```

Make sure you prepare your class for static mocks by using below annotation on top of test class

```
    @PrepareForTest(YourClassNameWhereYouWantToInjectStaticMock.class)
```

And run your Test with 
      `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)`.